# Cocos2D - repeating an action using a loop on several CCSprites does not work as expected... why?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This works:

```
for (Object *oneObj in allObjects) {

    id moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3f position:ccp(tx, ty)];
    id rotateAction = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.3 angle:0.0f];

    id action = [CCSpawn actions:moveAction, rotateAction, nil];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: action,
                                     [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1f],
                                     nil];

    [oneObj runAction:sequence];
}
```

This does not work (just one object is moved by this one):

```
id moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3f position:ccp(tx, ty)];
id rotateAction = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.3 angle:0.0f];

id action = [CCSpawn actions:moveAction, rotateAction, nil];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions: action,
                          [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1f],
                          nil];

for (Object *oneObj in allObjects) {
     [oneObj runAction:sequence];
}
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because one action can only run on one node. You have to copy the sequence so each object runs its own copy of the sequence:

```
[oneObj runAction:[sequence copy]];
```